# Twitter xAuth vs open source

Tags: open-source, twitter, oauth, xauth

I am developing an open source desktop twitter client. I would like to take advantage on the new xAuth authentication method, however my app is open source which means that if I put the keys directly into the source file, it may be a vulnerability (am I correct? The twitter support guy told me).

On the other hand, putting the key directly into a binary also doesn't make sense. I am writing my application in python, so if I just supply the pyc files, it is one more seconds to get the keys, thanks to the excellent reflection capatibilities of Python. If I create a small .so file with the keys, it is also trivial to obtain the key by looking at the raw binary (keys has fixed length and character set).

What is your opinion? Is it really a secutiry hole to expose the API keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Security hole? In broad terms, yes.  Realistically though, these aren't nuclear launch codes we're talking about.

About the worst thing that could happen is that someone could take and use your app's keys to do something against Twitter's TOS that will end up getting the keys banned.  No user data would be vulnerable since you're not distributing the user tokens (that would be much worse from a security standpoint). Since anyone can register an app in 2 seconds at no cost, the only reason to do that kind of impersonation would be specifically to besmirch the reputation of you or your app.

One thing you could do is leave them out of the source code but make it clear that user's compiling from source need to obtain their own keys and put them in the appropriate place, but leave them in the binary version that you distribute.  Not 100% secure, but makes it that little bit harder that will deter a certain number of n'er-do-wells.

Comment: I came to a something similar conclusion. My application is open source, but the keys are propiertary. If the keys are not present, then the app falls back to the old authentication method (this is quite easy, thanks to python and tweepy).